# How do you merge a multiple 2d list thats not the same length?

Tags: python-3.x, multidimensional-array

Good morning I'm trying to merge two or more 2d list together that doesnt have the same length. 
For example below I have two different multidimensional list that doesnt have the same length.

```
A=[[1,2,3],[4,7,19]]
B=[[2,4], [3],[5,7,9]]
```

If this is possible what code do I use to get the results below.

```
C=[[[1,2,3,2,4],[1,2,3,3],[1,2,3,5,7,9]],[[4,7,19,2,4],[4,7,19,3],[4,7,19,5,7,9]]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a nested [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> [[a + b for b in B] for a in A]
[[[1, 2, 3, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3], [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9]], [[4, 7, 19, 2, 4], [4, 7, 19, 3], [4, 7, 19, 5, 7, 9]]]
```

`a` and `b` are each sub-list of `A` and `B`, respectively. The comprehension takes the first member of `A` in the outer `for a in A` and cycles through each sub-list of `B`, adding each one to `a` in turn. Then the next `a` in `A` is selected and the process keeps repeating until there are no more members of `A` left.

Comment: @outkast20 sure, as long as you don't run out of memory. If that's actually an issue, I'd consider using NumPy arrays instead, as you can concatenate them in place without making copies of them in memory.

Comment: Ok I sure did ran into a issue. How do I use it with Numpy arrays?

Comment: @outkast20 I've been playing around with NumPy and Pandas for a while, trying to figure out how to make it work, with no success, as my knowledge here is rather limited. I suspect you might be able to do it using a Pandas `DataFrame` and your original sub-lists (as lists instead of `np.array`s) in two columns, but I'm stuck on how to do the broadcasting without duplicating the data in memory. I'd ask a new question about how to do that in Pandas, referencing this question and my answer for the pure Python way.

Comment: No problem. Hopefully I at least got you pointed in the right direction.